# How to get the max retry count within an MDB?

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I can read the current delivery count using javax.jms.Message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"). I'm trying to read the current max retry setting. I configured it to be 5 using following configuration in jms-service.xml.

```
<attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">5</attribute>
```

But when I try read it using

- javax.jms.Message.propertyExists("dLQMaxResent") [JBoss](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/JBoss_Messaging_User_Guide/ch05s11.html)
- javax.jms.Message.propertyExists("MaxDeliveryAttempts")
- javax.jms.Message.propertyExists("DLQMaxResent")
- javax.jms.Message.propertyExists("MaxDeliveryCnt") [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/actcfgprop.htm)

All of the above return false. I'm using JBoss EAP 5.0.1 with jboss messaging.

Any suggestions on which property I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MaDa rightly says so, this is MBean configuration.

Using following code you can read any JMX MBean setting in JBoss envrionment.

```
javax.management.MBeanServer server = org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
server.getAttribute(new javax.management.ObjectName(mbeanName), attributeName);
```

e.g.

```
server.getAttribute(new javax.management.ObjectName("jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=testQueue"),"MaxDeliveryAttempts");
```

For this you will need to include [jboss-jmx.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jboss-jmx/4.0.2) in your maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What you're setting by `<attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">` is **MBean** configuration, but then you're trying to read it from the **message**. Why should it be there?

Comment: Can you read the max delivery attempts from message at all?. Even if I don't set it, it defaults to 10. I want to be able to read the current setting.